# How to add a double value and a list element which is in double?

Tags: java

I tried a code

```
double temp=0;
List list=new ArrayList();
list.add(1.1);
temp+=list.get(0); //error occurs here
```

Error that occurred is as follows

> bad operand types for binary operator '+'
>
> first type: double
>
> second type: Object

What should I do to add the temp value and the double value in the list?

The programming language that I preferred is Java.

Comment: Always use Generic type of List. Use `List<Double>`

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing my doubt within seconds

Comment: @RohitJain: I think that comment deserves to be an answer (with a brief mention of autounboxing).

Comment: Yes sir, its an answer to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always use `Generic type` for your `Collections` type like `List`, `ArrayList`, so on, when programming in `Java 1.5+`.

When you use a `raw type` List, then the method `List.get(0)` will always give you `Object` type, which you would need to do some casting to get it to work.

So, either you can add a casting to `Double` in your current code, which is absolutely a bad idea.

Or, you should use `generic` version of List as below: -

```
List<Double> list=new ArrayList<Double>();
list.add(1.1);
```

Note that, the value `1.1` is a `double`, still it can be added directly, without the need to convert it to `Double`. This is because of the feature of `Java` called `Auto Boxing`.

In Java, when you store a `double` value in a `Double` reference, then the `double` value is automatically boxed into `Double`. While in reverse case, it is called `Unboxing`, i.e. from `Double` to `double`.

That is why, when you do: -

```
temp+=list.get(0);
```

the value of `list.get(0)` is of type `Double`. And since you are performing an operation with `double` primitive type, that vlaue is automatically `boxed` to `double`, and addition operation is performed.

Comment: This gives me the perfect answer. Thank you Sir

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the primitive wrapper class Double.

```
List<Double> list=new ArrayList<Double>();
list.add(new Double(1.1));
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap 1.1 in Double.

Comment: @Rohit Jain , true, thanks for the correction, I didn't take into account the autoboxing.

Answer (score 2):

When you don't define the Generic Type. The list will return an object. Which means that you need to cast it:

```
temp+=(Double) list.get(0);
```

Though it is easier to just define the generic type directly in the declaration of the list:

```
List<Double> list=new ArrayList();
```

on a side note:

You need to use `Double` instead of `double` for this to work. Because `double` is a primitive type while `Double` is a java object that the list can store